# DataGridView C# Help Needed

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb, cell

So I have a DGV connected to my Visual C# via OleDB with my information in it and I need to take the text from a cell when clicking the cell. I know I can't take it from the DGV, I need to get it from de OleDB DataSet. But how do I tell the program which DGV cell I need to take the text from? And how would the DataSet Codeline be?
Any help will be thanked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get cell value,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot man. even some dumbass had told me this wasn't possible

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using the following event handler. It fires each time the DataGridView is edited, so if you click on any cell it will fire. Below is a basic example of grabbing the data from current selected cell. Have a play about with it.

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
           var result =  dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but I assume you have confused C# with some other, since C# doesn't use vars. Again, thanks anyway :D

Comment: hey @user1832697 var is .net,came up with ver 3.5,4.0

Comment: :PokerFace: to be honest, I have no ideda what you're talking about, Good Sir.

Comment: var determines the object type itself rather than the creator stating it. Its a shorthand thing I use. I think its pretty common pal.